# Skobbler SDK for Android: onAnnotationSelected not called on 2.1.0 version

Tags: android, sdk, skmaps

I used 2.1.0 version of SDK. Here is my code which adds annotation to map:

```
SKAnnotation annotation = new SKAnnotation();
annotation.setUniqueID(10);
annotation.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(30.5234, 50.4501));
annotation.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_MARKER);
annotation.setMininumZoomLevel(5);
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation);
```

When I tap on this annotation SKMapSurfaceListener.onAnnotationSelected() not called. Logcat:

```
I/MapActivity.onMapActionDown():205﹕ onMapActionDown()
D/SKMaps﹕ SKMapSurfaceView----SINGLE TAP  CONFIRMED null
D/SKMaps﹕ SKMapSurfaceView----Check north indicator   4 124.74013 414.43448 0 0 0 0
D/SKMaps﹕ SKMapSurfaceView----notifyWithMapInfo
D/SKMaps﹕ SKMapSurfaceView---- Tapped custom POI id=-1187666264
I/MapActivity.onSingleTap():185﹕ onSingleTap()
D/SKMaps﹕ MapRenderer----ANIMATION FINISH CALLBACK
I/MapActivity.onMapRegionChangeEnded():175﹕ onMapRegionChangeEnded()
```

Previous version of SDK worked normally.

Comment: Could you share some details regarding the device/OS version where you are testing? (the QA team caught a similar error on a Samsung Galaxy Mini with SDK version 10 but we could not reproduce this issue on any other devices)

Comment: @Ando I use Genymotion emulator with Nexus S 4.2.2 system image. Also I checked this issue on real device with android 4.0.4 - worked properly.